# my webpack cannot find my index.html page when I run npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am new to using the node.js and its packages, so I started with running the npm init to create the package.json below:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.54.4",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

I then ran the npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server css-loader sass-loader sass extract-loader file-loader to generate the dependencies as well as the package-lock.json file and the node modules.

I then created an app.scss file with some styling, and a index.html file with some basic html code like hello world:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
  </head>
  <body>Hello World</body>
</html>
```

I then proceeded to create a webpack.config.js with the following code:

```
module.exports = [{
entry: './app.scss',
  output: {
    filename: 'style-bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'bundle.css',
            },
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // Prefer Dart Sass
              implementation: require('sass'),

              // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804
              webpackImporter: false,
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}];
```

However, when I run "npm start" and try to access the index.html page through the http://localhost:8080/, I get the Cannot GET / error. I even added the index.html prefix after the localhost just incase, yet it still throws same error.

Can someone help check what I am doing incorrectly please?

Comment: Are you getting the compiled CSS file?

Comment: No I am not. Not even getting the html page

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but you seem to miss the basics of Webpack. You can get an answer for this specific question but it won't help you long term. I would suggest you to follow the [Get started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/) on the official doc. Really good and simple tutorial to get Webpack in its core.

Answer (score 0):

Why your entry point to .scss file? Webpack is a module bundle for Javascript. I think you should read webpack's concept and change your entry, write some script and using html plugin.

Comment: Please read the documentation about what a good SO answer needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you, i will notice it